# Access header component element height in router-outlet - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a requirement to get header element height in my router-outlet component. I have to generate dynamic height in one of my component, using header height. Which is the best way I can apply for this. Please advice

**app.compoenet.html**

```
<div #headerRef>
    <header><header>
</div>
<div class="content"  #contentRef>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div #footerRef>
    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

**header.component.html**

```
<header> <!--- some code ---> </header>
```

**component-mapped-in-outlet.ts**

```
//some code
let nHeaderHeight = some code
// some code
```

Comment: can you use a service to save this height and when the app component loads you can reference your header element to get the height and save it inside of your service. Which you can then use in any of your 'routed' components to access it

Comment: Hi Nico, I already tried the same and its worked. But I am checking any other better way available or not?

Comment: There are 3 angular ways of doing component interaction:
By reference,
By Parent (Input & Output),
By Service

Obviously you can do it a *javascript way* but i would strongly recommend against it as it can lead to other unforeseen problems

You can see some examples here: https://medium.com/dailyjs/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

Answer (score 0):

In header component write a function that gets height. Then store it in service and access anywhere you want.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.sampleService.headerHeight = window.innerHeight;
}
```

Comment: I don't think Output works for components which are injected into the DOM from the router

Comment: Actually in the example header was not in router outlet. If so , he needs to store the height in service and access it anywhere.

Comment: OP said:
I have a requirement to *get* header element height in *my router-outlet component*.